# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS app running on i9-9980XE twice as slow as older, smaller PC

Tags: drivers, kernel

Is the reason that our new i9-9980XE, 128GB RAM, X-299 MB, 18cores is running the application on Ubuntu 14.04.5 in 10 hours versus and older i7, 64GB RAM, 4 cores in 5 hours because of the old kernel?  What is the newest kernel that I can install in 14.04.5 and still have it function?  The application must run on 14.04.5.

Comment: What is the app that you are running to compare?  Also, was the app written to be optimized on an 18 core system?  Having more cores doesn't mean that the app will run faster.

Comment: The app is processing 3D point cloud scans, merging/cleaning them and uses as many core/threads available plus approximately 3 GB of RAM per thread.  So theoretically it should be running 36/8 times faster but is taking twice as long to complete.  Cpus are both overclocked at 4.2GHz.

Comment: If you use the system monitor to look at the cpu cores/threads, are they all busy?

Comment: Well, in theory you should be able to install any of the kernels that you want into Ubuntu 14.04.5 but it may or may not work.  However, Ubuntu 14.04 will go [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) in April sometime so there will be no more updates or support for it.  You can look into if the application programmers have been able to produce a new version of the app, or you can look into using a kernel from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: The application folks will be moving the app hopefully before April, 2019 to 18.04 with no specific date yet.

Comment: All 36 threads appear to be busy, but not sure if they are all productive (probably not).